# How to Aggregate Items of Same Index in an Array

Tags: arrays, sql-server, string, aggregate

I have this data in an array/string

| DateTime | Column A |
| --- | --- |
| 4/1/2022 17:00 | [10,5,1,0,2] |
| 4/1/2023 18:00 | [5,2,0,1,3] |

Expected Output is

| Date | Column A |
| --- | --- |
| 4/1/2022 | [15,7,1,1,5] |

Tried splitting with comma as delimiter but there are a lot of items in a column; table above is just a sample column with 5 items. Actual data contains 16 items separated by comma in one column (other Columns have more).

Comment: I don't follow the requirement here. Where do `15` and `7` come from? Why is `0` and `2` gone?

Comment: @ThomA Sum the arrays so 10+5, 5+2, etc.

Comment: The real answer here is: do not store lists of things in a single string column.

Comment: Are you doing matrix additions in sql?

Answer (score 1):

This is a little messy in my opinion, but "works". You'll want to treat your data like JSON here, as (at least for the sample we have) it is a valid JSON array.

We can split the data into rows using `OPENJSON` and then aggregate each `key` (which is effectively the ordinal position). This gives us the values you want, but in row form.

After that we can then use `STRING_AGG`, with a couple of brackets (`[]`) concatenated at each end to remake the JSON array::

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT MIN(CONVERT(date,V.DateTime)) AS [Date],
           SUM(TRY_CONVERT(int,value)) AS Agg,
           OJ.[key]
    FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(datetime2(0),'4/1/2022 17:00',103),N'[10,5,1,0,2]'),
                (CONVERT(datetime2(0),'4/1/2023 18:00',103),N'[5,2,0,1,3]'))V(DateTime,ColumnA)
         CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(V.ColumnA) OJ
    GROUP BY OJ.[key])
SELECT [Date],
       N'[' + STRING_AGG(Agg,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [key]) + N']' AS ColumnA
FROM CTE
GROUP BY [Date];
```